# In what site can I ask about the comparative characteristics of a family of languages?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

In February 2021, I asked the question [Pronunciation of "ll" in the Romance languages](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/pronunciation-of-ll-in-the-romance-languages) on the Language Learning site. I received 2 answers and I accepted 1 answer. However, my question was closed as off-topic in less than a year.
Which is the correct site where I can ask a question about the characteristics of a language?

Comment: Since you're a member of [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com), have you already considered posting there?

Comment: You question was closed because it's too broad and it doesn't have any examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a Stack Exchange dedicated to [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/); according to their [Help Center](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), they welcome questions about

> - Linguistics phenomena during history
>
> ...
>
> - linguistic analysis of specific language features or examples

Also important, it does not fall under

> - Language-specific grammar and usage questions

because it seems to be about a language *family* rather than a single language.

I'm not a regular there but IMHO your question would be a decent fit, though you could improve it by sharing your research so far (which is true for *all* Stack Exchange sites).